# Selecting values between 2 dates

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am currently working on a website that offers tutoring services and I have been stuck on this issue quite a while..

I have 2 text boxes where the user chooses a start date and a finish date, when the user clicks view he would be suppose to see the results in a gridview. I am using FormParameters to insert the date into the query.

SelectCommand of the sqldatasource

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [Session].Session_num AS Num, [Session].Session_Time_Stamp AS Session_Date, Student.Student_First &amp; ' ' &amp; Student.Student_Last AS Student FROM (([Session] INNER JOIN Student ON [Session].Student_Num = Student.Student_Num) INNER JOIN Class ON [Session].Class_ID = Class.Class_ID) WHERE ((([Session].Session_Time_Stamp) Between @firstdate And @seconddate))">
```

Parameters of the SqlDataSource

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:FormParameter Name="firstdate" Type="DateTime"/>
    <asp:FormParameter Name="seconddate" Type="DateTime"/>
</SelectParameters>
```

This is executed when the user clicks the view button, it is where I set the values of the parameters and execute the sql select.

```
Dim fdate As DateTime = Format(CDate(txtStartDate.Text), "MM/dd/yyyy")
Dim ldate As DateTime = Format(CDate(txtEndDate.Text), "MM/dd/yyyy")
gridTutor.SelectParameters("firstdate").DefaultValue = fdate
gridTutor.SelectParameters("seconddate").DefaultValue = ldate
gridTutor.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty)
gridTutorSessions.DataBind()
```

fdate and ldate are not empty, however after this is executed the query result is empty. Could it be that wrong methods to execute the select?

Edit: I realized the problem is probably with the query and DateTime format. When I transformed my textbox value to DateTime it put it like this #2/20/2014#. However, it doesn't return anything even if there are values between the two dates. 
If anybody have an access query with DateTime I would like to see it. Thanks

Comment: So where is the code that is actually executing the updated Select command after you have applied the parameters...? Give us more context please.

Comment: It's strange that you get a string, convert it to a date with CDate, then convert it back to a string with Format to put it inside a date.

Comment: I would add a breakpoint on "gridTutor.SelectParameters("firstdate").DefaultValue = fdate", ensure that the values of firstdate and seconddate are actually being populated (not blanks)

Comment: @the_lotus It's VB.  People do all sorts of horrible things like that all the time.  I've seen many cases where they don't even both to explicitly convert anything at all.

Comment: @smclark89 They are not blank they are return values in this format: #01/01/1990#

Comment: @Douglas Barbin It's the only code that works for me to convert the string to a date ParseExact() didn't work for me.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn Thanks for the input mate, but still doesn't display anything nothing.

Comment: dumb question.... you load it in gridTutor but you are binding gridTutorSessions. what is the difference between the two?

Comment: 1. You're still not showing us where you execute the query. 2. What's  '&amp' doing in your SQL?  3. what happens if you run the query in SSMS?

Comment: @peterG 1. To be honest, I'm not used to running select queries with formparameter usually I use the controlparamater however this time I can't, but isn't gridTutor.Select() suppose to execute it? 2. '&amp'is the code for &. 3. Thank you for asking this! I hcecked in access it works however in my sqldatasource GUI it doesn't show anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by formatting the date in my access database it's not the best solution but it is a fix for the situation

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to manually set fdate and ldate just before you do your 'selectparameters' (i.e. use "fdate = Format(CDate(txtStartDate.Text), "MM/dd/yyyy")".  According to the following, values asigned to Dim in the manner you have would not reflect the realtime values you want.  See the following regarding VB: "You can assign a value to a variable when it is created. For a value type, you use an initializer to supply an expression to be assigned to the variable. The expression must evaluate to a constant that can be calculated at compile time.